# VBA: Write info from my spreadsheet to TXT file saved on my mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am trying to use a code that can write info from my spreadsheet to .txt file saved on my mac.

However, when I run it in Excel for Mac 2016, it gives me this error:

> Runtime error "424"

I have this in Microsoft Visual Basic:

```
Sub October Week 1()

Dim i As Integer
Dim Line As String

outputFile = FreeFile
Open "/Users/NickName/Documents/Project/script.txt" For Output As 
#outputFile

Dim filename As String

For i = 5 To 198

If Cells(i, 2).Value = "TOPIC" Then
a.WriteLine "Cells(i, 3).Value"
a.WriteLine "Blank Space"
Else
a.WriteLine "H1" + Cells(i, 4).Value + "H1"
a.WriteLine "Blank Space"
a.WriteLine "Cells(i,5).Value + Cells(i, 8).Value + Cells(i, 4).Value"
a.WriteLine "Blank Space"
End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Not familiar with Excel for Mac but, what does FreeFile and outputFile means? Are those variables? If those are variables, you are not declaring and setting the values properly.

Comment: outputFile can be declared as an integer, and FreeFile assigns an available file number (handle) to that integer. I think that part looks OK. #outputFile shouldn't be on its own line; it should be after the "As"...is that just word wrapping? I would think you'd get a compile error. I'm also not clear about the name of your Sub....are there really spaces in "October Week 1()"? What is "a" supposed to represent? Is that declared elsewhere?

Comment: @Manel Lopez On which line ?

Comment: The very first line... you cannot have a space in the name of a subroutine.

Answer (score 0):

A good first step is to Google the error code.  Here is [more information on Error 424 "Object Required"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/object-required-error-424).

I'm not a Mac user (and I, too, am surprised that you are allowed to use *spaces* in the name of the Sub), but the reason for the error is that **VBA doesn't know what you are referring to** with: `a.`

You don't refer to `a.` prior to your WriteLine statements.  [Here are some examples](https://www.google.ca/search?q=excel%20write%20to%20text%20file%20tutorial) of how to write to a text file.  VBA context should be the same between Mac text & Windows.